# synchronizing access 2 variables in a loop in bash

Tags: bash

```
peterc@peterc-ml video $ VAR1="foo maltese mountain"
peterc@peterc-ml video $ VAR2="bar falcon goat"
peterc@peterc-ml video $ for X in 1 2 3
> do
> echo ??????
> done
```

The desired output is:

```
 foo bar
 maltese falcon
 mountain goat
```

Both VAR1 and VAR2 will always have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cut(1)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cut):

```
echo ${VAR1} | cut -d " " -f ${X}
```

Comment: Drive-by downvote?  This example *does* work, so it's hardly wrong.

Comment: Nice to see downvoting of right solution )) Nobody want to think how to get complete solution from this one... +1

Answer (score 2):

Make an array out of each.

```
ARR1=( $VAR1 )
ARR2=( $VAR2 )
for (( i = 0; i < ${#ARR1[@]}; i++)); do 
    echo ${ARR1[i]} ${ARR2[i]}
done
```

e.g.

```
$ VAR1="a b c"
$ VAR2="1 2 3"
$ ARR1=( $VAR1 )
$ ARR2=( $VAR2 )
$ for (( i = 0; i < ${#ARR1[@]}; i++)); do 
>     echo ${ARR1[i]} ${ARR2[i]}
> done
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
paste -d ' ' <(tr ' ' '\n' <<< "$VAR1") <(tr ' ' '\n' <<< "$VAR2")
```